# Is there a difference between Dragon's Dogma and Dragon's Dogma: Dark Arisen?

Tags: dragons-dogma

I'm interested in buying Dragon's Dogma, but there are two versions available.

- Dragon's Dogma *(incl. 100 special quests)*
- Dragon's Dogma: Dark Arisen

I've read that the second one is like an expantionpack, but I don't know if I need the first one to play through it or if it's better to play the regular one first. Or is it just like a GOTY-Edition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dragon's Dogma: Dark Arisen` includes `Dragon's Dogma` plus some additional content:

> Dark Arisen includes the full version of Dragon’s Dogma – with a few
>   minor adjustments – as well as a good 10 to 15 hours of new
>   adventuring on a mysterious black island that rises from the sea
>   outside the fishing village of Cassardis.

[from here](http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/04/30/dragons-dogma-dark-arisen-review).

Answer (score 1):

in dragon's dogma you get a unlimted supply of ferrystones if you play dark arisen **afterwards**. in dragon's dogma ferry stones cost 20,000 gold but in dark arisen it only cost 2,000 gold.  plus you can buy portcystuls for 30,000 gold in new games plus.  bitter black isle you have to face new enemy's such as: banshees, wargs, wraths, grams, corrupt pawns, gorecyclops, ect...,and the most dangeous....DEATH (a.k.a. the grim reaper.)  it also has new items that can heal you all the way or most of your health like: lordly tonic, Godly Analeptic, ect...

hope this helps.